# CD and DVD burning very slow with LG DVD Burner

Tags: windows, dvd, burning, compact-disc

I have an HP m7560in Desktop which came with an LG DVD burner. As far back as I can remember, it has been having problems in burning discs. It used to take about one and a half hour to burn 4 GB of data on a blank DVD-R. I am using Nero and ImgBurn and I usually select 8x speed for burning. I used to run XP earlier and now I run Windows 7 on it, but I face the problem on both.

**I have already checked that DMA mode is selected in the IDE controllers' properties.** On XP, uninstalling the IDE controllers and DVD drive from the Device Manager, rebooting and letting it install the drivers again fixed the problem for a while, but after a couple reboots, the problem used to come back.

On Windows 7, even doing that is not fixing the problem. In fact, in Windows 7, the burning process doesn't even begin.  Imgburn gets stuck on the first stage (of writing Lead-In), and it never progresses until I turn off / reset the computer. I checked the disc info after this happened, and the disc still shows empty and ready to be burned on, so it's obvious that it didn't even touch the disc.

I have already had the drive replaced once by HP, but it didn't fix the problem. Do you guys have any suggestions? (Note that Windows Updates doesn't give any newer driver for the controllers, or any other components for that matter).